# open bootstrap drop down submenu on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have a navbar which has a drop down functionality i have customized it according to my requirements here's my initial code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-center">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="navbar-logo" class="img-responsive" src="images/navbar_logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#"><img id="navbar-home" src="images/navbar_home.png" class="img-responsive"/></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT US<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu  arrow-up">
                                    <li><a href="ourcompany.php">OUR COMPANY</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="ouraccomplishments.php">OUR ACCOMPLISHMENTS</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="ourteam.php">OUR DOCTORS</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="research.php">RESEARCH</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="icare.php">ICARE</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">EYE EDUCATION<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu  arrow-up">
                                    <li><a href="ourcompany.php">MY VISIT</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="ouraccomplishments.php">OUR ACCOMPLISHMENTS</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="ourteam.php">OUR DOCTORS</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="research.php">RESEARCH</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="icare.php">ICARE</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">FEMTO CATARACT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PROCEDURES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="diagnostic.php">DIAGNOSTICS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<!--                            <li><a href="#"><img id="navbar-search" src="images/navbar_search.png" class="img-responsive"/></a></li>-->
                            <li><a class="navbar-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">BOOK AN APPOINMENT</a></li>
                            <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><img id="navbar-list" src="images/navbar_list.png" class="img-responsive list"/></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
            </nav>
```

**css**

```
.navbar .brand {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
    padding: 9px 15px 8px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar{
    font-family: young;
    clear: both;
}
.navbar a{
    color: #515254;
}
.navbar-nav{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
    float: left;
}
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus{
    color: #007f3d;
    background: none;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: raleway-regular;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.navbar-nav img.list{
    margin-top: -13px;
}
.navbar-nav .navbar-button{
    background-color:#1c74bc;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 1px solid #1c74bc;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:raleway-regular;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:10px 25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a{
    font-family: raleway-regular;
    color: #848484;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu{
    border-top: 3px solid #1c75bc;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #1c75bc;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.navbar-nav .arrow-up::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #1c75bc;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -11px;
}
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background: none;
}
```

**javascript**

```
 $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(300);
    });
```

now what happening is i am opening a boostrap dropdown on hover so far it is working fine now what i want to do is open another nested drop down on hover the same way the parent drop down is opening and in the same styling i am trying hard but everytime i get an issue some times the code doesnt work and sometimes the styling gets mixed up! help!

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9hx6du61/)

Comment: Which other dropdown are you trying to open inside of the current dropdown?

Comment: just the same one as the current but on the right side as you may see on may websites